# Importing JavaScript files into QML in qt creator

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator

I am having trouble importing js file into a QML file. What I want to do is to put some constant values (that might be changed later) in a JavaScript file and import it in my QML file. Here is the js file:

```
 //autolayoutconstants.js
.pragma library

/// The X coordinate to start autolayout
var oX = 10;
/// The Y coordinate to start autolayout
var oY = 10;
//some other vars
```

And this is how I import it in the QML file:

```
import "qrc:/ProjectEditor/autolayoutconstants.js" as ALConsts
```

And in the same file I try to use the values I defined in this way:

```
 var sX = ALConsts.oX;
 var sY = ALConsts.oY;
```

But the sX and sY values will be treated as they have the value `0`!!! I get no error/warning so I have no idea what could be wrong.

**UPDATE**

I figured out that if I change the import statement and remove the `qrc:/` and the directory, it will work OK! I mean I had to do the following change:

```
import "autolayoutconstants.js" as ALConsts
```

I don't understand why? so my question is now if someone can explain the reason. Maybe it is something with project structure or qt creator?

Comment: I suppose it's the way the qml engine searches for resources and the syntax to do that.. somewhat arbitrary.

Comment: We don't use the resource prefix when loading any qml files except the main file.  You might read through this documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-deployment.html#managing-resource-files-with-the-qt-resource-system

Comment: @RetiredNinja But I have seen and have some sample codes that contain the `qrc:` statement for the imports. How is that?

Comment: Perhaps those files are in a different resource bundle than the main file or there's some other reason.  Hard to say without seeing the code in question.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I think I know what you mean. So is there a way that I move my newly created js file to a bundle? which way is better? I mean for the case that I want to put my js file somewhere else. If you like, you can answer this and I mark your answer!